# Value of variable not being displayed

Tags: batch-file

Can someone tell me what's the problem with the below batch script? I don't get MYTIME in the final output.

```
@ECHO ON


SET CURRENTTIME=%TIME%
IF "%CURRENTTIME:~0,1%"==" " (SET CURRENTTIME=0%CURRENTTIME:~1%)
FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=/." %%a in ("%CURRENTTIME%") do (set MYTIME = %%a)

FOR /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%A IN ('DATE /T') DO (SET TIMESTAMP=%%C-%%A-%%B)

ECHO %TIMESTAMP%-%MYTIME%

PAUSE
```

Let us say the Date is 21 July 2015 and time is 04h:05m:06s.5ms.

The output I expect is 2015-07-21-04:05:06
But the output is 2015-07-21-

Answer (score 1):

```
                         set MYTIME = %%a
space included in variable name....^ ^.. Space included in value
```

So you end with `%MYTYME %` variable. Better use

```
set "MYTIME=%%a"
```

Comment: now I am unable to rename a file with the below command.

ren C:\Reports\FXCM\TEST.CSV TEST_%TIMESTAMP%-%MYTIME%.csv
It returns 
ren C:\Reports\FXCM\TEST.CSV TEST_2015-07-2
1-05:21:12.csv
A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.
though the file exists and no duplicates.

Comment: There is a space between the date day values in the new filename. `TEST_2015-07-2 1-05:21:12.csv`

Comment: I dont see a space when I echoTIMESTAMP..  But I get  space when I try to rename the file..
any idea?

Comment: I realised that the issue is because the separator(:) in time stamp. Thanks for your help..